# Firebase, retrieving through getter is successful except for one specific value

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

This is weird, I have a working code to retrieve a set of data including Long, String, int, work perfectly. (eg: "player1Name" in this example)

But when I add one more item, String "observerCode" through updateGameInfo(), it cannot retrieve for no reason, just retrieved a blank text to display ..

```
public void updateGameInfo() {

 DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
 DatabaseReference gameInfoRef = rootRef.child("gameInfo").child(UserId);.

 game.put("player1Name", tv_player1Name.getText().toString());
 game.put("observerCode", "TESTING");
 gameInfoRef.child(gameKey).updateChildren(game);
 }
```

onClick retrieving data:

```
 gameInfoRef.child(gameKey).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                TextView tv_observerCode = findViewById(R.id.tv_observerCode);

                    GameFan gameFan1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(GameFan.class);
                    String observerCode = gameFan1.getObserverCode();
                    tv_observerCode.setText(observerCode);

                }
```

my GameFan class:

```
public class GameFan {

public GameFan() {
}

public String observerCode;
public String player1Name;

public String getObserverCode() {
    return observerCode;
}
public void setObserverCode(String observerCode) {
    observerCode = observerCode;
}

public String getPlayer1Name() {
    return player1Name;
}
public void setPlayer1Name(String player1Name) {
    this.player1Name = player1Name;
}
```

Firebase:

```
 -LSiDqymAufeTWgsJE5q //the gameKey
      observerCode: "TESTING"
      player1Name: "player1"
```

Result: When clicked the button, it changes my TextView from some sample Text to nothing, matching the background color. No errors. Then when I change this line

```
 String observerCode = gameFan1.getobserverCode();
```

to

```
 String observerCode = gameFan1.getPlayer1Name();
```

it changes my TextView to "player1", I am so confused, how could this even happen!

Answer (score 1):

Your getter and setter are not named correctly.  The should get `getObserverCode` and `setObserverCode`.  Note the capital O.

Comment: I edited my question to correct the capital O problem, but still the result is the same...